# Receiving advanced payments to post something on my facebook page

Tags: investing

I have a facebook page and recently i am receiving such messages, as context seems valid , its like helping people so their article to be shown and i get money from them. The money is tempting, and my page has a good reach somehow up to arround 500 thousand people. But I dont feel good about that. By the way this question about money,  in case i dont get close votes.[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is this legal on facebook receiving advanced money just sharing some articles or post?. Is it a possible way of money landering

Comment: Edit your question to ask your question. Also pick tags that apply to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Signs it's a scam:
 * Too good to be true
 * Misspelling of Western Union

Comment: I'd also be very suspicious of what sort of websites / posts is it directing traffic to. Notice the complete lack of specifics and focus on getting you to agree to it before finding out what it is.